Gear trains of astronomical clocks available?
I have been modelling gear trains of astronomical clocks (e.g., Antikythera, Eise Eisinga Planetarium, Prague Orloj, Ancient Maya Solar System).
I am now looking for gear trains of other famous astronomical clocks, like the one in Strasbourg (France) and in Berne (Switzerland). Any info highly appreciated!

An interesting idea for an undergraduate SolidWorks class…
